# Problems with vagrant, centos, dhclient

Tags: linux, centos, vagrant

I have a problem, where the centos dhclient script keeps overwriting my /etc/resolv.conf file.

I'm using a centos7 image with vagrant 1.7.2

I have a pretty simple setup, here is my `VagrantFile`

```
config.vm.define "puppetmaster" do |pm|

    ## Map the local puppet configuration to the puppetmaster
    pm.vm.synced_folder "./puppetmaster", "/etc/puppet"



    pm.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|

        puppet.manifests_path = ["vm", "/etc/puppet/manifests"]
        puppet.manifest_file = "site.pp"

    end

    pm.vm.box = "puppetlabs/centos-7.0-64-puppet"
    pm.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.2.2"

    ## Enable the GUI
    pm.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
            v.gui = true
            v.name = "mattlab-puppetmaster"
            v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory",2048]
            v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus",4]
    end

end
```

As you can see, I only have a network single interface configured and it's got some static settings.

I know Vagrant also has an internal interface, which it uses for communication. This seems to pick an IP using DHCP (although i'm not certain where this comes from).

I know that having a single dhcp interface will trigger the dhclient script to overwrite the resolv.conf.

As this box will be a puppetmaster and DNS server, I need to find a way to disable the vagrant dhcp interface in a way that will

My interfaces look like

```
[root@puppetmaster dhcp]# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:19:cd:16 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
    valid_lft 81995sec preferred_lft 81995sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe19:cd16/64 scope link 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:85:18:83 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.2/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global enp0s8
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe85:1883/64 scope link 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

1. Still allow me to connect via the command line with `vagrant ssh`
2. Allow vagrant to use my static 192.168.2.2 address instead of the dhcp address.

Does this sound possible ?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, answered my own question.

When `dhclient-script` generates a new `/etc/resolv.conf` it looks for a function called `make_resolv_conf()`.

By putting the following in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks` and making it executable, it stops overwriting it.

```
make_resolv_conf() {
    # Do not overwrite /etc/resolv.conf.
    return 0
}
```

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 0):

I resolved in `Centos7`. I hope it helps you.

In `ifcfg-eth0` (in my case) it was set `PEERDNS="yes"`. Changing to `PEERDNS="no"` does not resolve the problem. But

```
PEERDNS="no"
export PEERDNS

ifup ifcfg-eth0
```

did work! I suspect it is a bug in `dhclient-script` or its caller.